# How to update a brmsfit object with a modified brms-generated stan model marginalizing over a distribution of weights

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, rstan, rstanarm

I would appreciate any help to update my brmsfit object with a modified brms-generated stan model because I want to pass various columns of weights to the likelihood in a way that brms does not support yet probably.

My objective is to obtain the posterior distribution of effects after marginalizing over the distribution of weights as discussed [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.05038.pdf).

I need to do this in brms or stanarm rather than stan directly because I want to use functions of https://github.com/mjskay/tidybayes that are currently not supported by a stanfit object.

The idea is probably similar to the one discussed at [Creating a brmsfit object with a modified brms-generated Stan model](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/creating-a-brmsfit-object-with-a-modified-brms-generated-stan-model/6840) but I am not certain how to do that in practice, so any help would be much appreciated.

> Additionally, I am not understanding how to implement in practice the
>   second and third lines of this explanation by [@paul.buerkner](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/creating-a-brmsfit-object-with-a-modified-brms-generated-stan-model/6840/2):
>
> Create an “empty” brmsfit object of your model via brm(..., chains =
>   0) . Generate and amend the Stan code and replace slot fit with the
>   output of rstan::stan_model (you may also want to change the Stan code
>   in slot model ). Run update(, recompile = FALSE)

**#the brms model to be modified and updated**

```
dt = read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
n r r/n group treat c2 c1 weights
62 3 0.048387097 1 0 0.1438 1.941115288 1.941115288
96 1 0.010416667 1 0 0.237 1.186583128 1.186583128
17 0 0 0 0 0.2774 1.159882668 3.159882668
41 2 0.048780488 1 0 0.2774 1.159882668 3.159882668
212 170 0.801886792 0 0 0.2093 1.133397521 1.133397521
143 21 0.146853147 1 1 0.1206 1.128993008 1.128993008
143 0 0 1 1 0.1707 1.128993008 2.128993008
143 33 0.230769231 0 1 0.0699 1.128993008 1.128993008
73 62 1.260273973 0 1 0.1351 1.121927228 1.121927228
73 17 0.232876712 0 1 0.1206 1.121927228 1.121927228")

m <-brm(r | trials(n) + weights(weights) ~ treat*c2+(1|group), 
              data=dt, family=binomial(link=logit))
```

**#the modified brms-generated stan model `modified_brms.stan`**

```
 functions { 
} 
data { 
  int<lower=1> N;  // total number of observations 
  int Y[N];  // response variable 
  int trials[N];  // number of trials 
  real<lower=0> weights[N, 10];  // model weights 
  int<lower=1> K;  // number of population-level effects 
  matrix[N, K] X;  // population-level design matrix 
  // data for group-level effects of ID 1
  int<lower=1> J_1[N];
  int<lower=1> N_1;
  int<lower=1> M_1;
  vector[N] Z_1_1;
  int prior_only;  // should the likelihood be ignored? 
} 
transformed data { 
  int Kc = K - 1; 
  matrix[N, K - 1] Xc;  // centered version of X 
  vector[K - 1] means_X;  // column means of X before centering 
  for (i in 2:K) { 
    means_X[i - 1] = mean(X[, i]); 
    Xc[, i - 1] = X[, i] - means_X[i - 1]; 
  } 
} 
parameters { 
  vector[Kc] b;  // population-level effects 
  real temp_Intercept;  // temporary intercept 
  vector<lower=0>[M_1] sd_1;  // group-level standard deviations
  vector[N_1] z_1[M_1];  // unscaled group-level effects
} 
transformed parameters { 
  // group-level effects 
  vector[N_1] r_1_1 = sd_1[1] * (z_1[1]);
} 
model { 
  vector[N] mu = temp_Intercept + Xc * b;
  for (n in 1:N) { 
    mu[n] += r_1_1[J_1[n]] * Z_1_1[n];
  } 
  // priors including all constants 
  target += student_t_lpdf(temp_Intercept | 3, 0, 10); 
  target += student_t_lpdf(sd_1 | 3, 0, 10)
    - 1 * student_t_lccdf(0 | 3, 0, 10); 
  target += normal_lpdf(z_1[1] | 0, 1);
  // likelihood including all constants 
  if (!prior_only) { 
    for (n in 1:N) 
    for (w in 1:10) {
      target += weights[n, w] * binomial_logit_lpmf(Y[n] | trials[n], mu[n]);
    }
  } 
} 
generated quantities { 
  // actual population-level intercept 
  real b_Intercept = temp_Intercept - dot_product(means_X, b); 
}
```

**#I am able to do this successfully, but not certain how to proceed from here:**

```
mod_modified_brms_stan <- stan_model(‘modified_brms.stan’)
```

This question has also been posted [here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/how-to-update-a-brmsfit-object-with-a-modified-brms-generated-stan-model/7567). Thanks in advance for any help.